# How to catch window resize?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I have the following code:
IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(CChildFrame, CMDIChildWnd)

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CChildFrame, CMDIChildWnd)
    ....
    //here I want make affect

    ....
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

and I want to call

```
CChildFrame::OnFrameResize
```

function when after the window is resized, so I tried this:

```
ON_WM_SIZING(&CChildFrame::OnFrameResize)
```

and

```
ON_WM_SIZE(&CChildFrame::OnFrameResize)
```

but neither works. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by 'it doesnt work'?

Answer (score 2):

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CChildFrame, CMDIChildWnd)
  //here I want make affect
  ON_WM_SIZE() // This will map the WM_SIZE message to CChildFrame::OnSize
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

// So put your resize code here:
void CChildFrame::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
}
```

Comment: you also want a declaration in the header: afx_msg void OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy);

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to override `abc()` with `xyz()` which is not possible, but `ON_WM_SIZE` can call only `OnSize()` function. To catch the resize event you have to override the `OnSize()` function and add `ON_WM_SIZE` to message mapping.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CChildFrame, CMDIChildWnd)
  ON_WM_SIZE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CChildFrame::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
  //Your stuff or function call OnFrameResize()
}
```